# Django dynamic deletion

Tags: python, django, optimization, django-queryset

So I have a large amount of objects that need to be deleted, but that will only set them to inactive as I override the `delete` methods on my models. I am trying to do this is the most optimal fashion. Given the number of objects, this will certainly take a couple minutes, but the shorter the better! Here is my situation:

```
object_list = [
    queryset_a,
    queryset_b,
    queryset_c,
    ...
]
for obj in object_list:
    #delete every item in the queryset (not calling queryset bulk delete, I have overridden the methods delete for a reason)
```

one way to do this would be a for loop:

```
for individual_obj in obj:
    individual_obj.delete()
```

## QUESTION

is that for loop the most optimal way to do this? **is there a faster way?**

## NOTE

the `delete()` functions on the models sometimes call signals, and those must go through.